# How to remove self intersecting parts of model after Bridge Edge loops?

Tags: mesh

I want to create a tight bend, i foutn that i can use Bridge Edge Loops to do so. But this creaates some self intersection. How can i remove the selfintersecting part and make the mesh cleaner?

Image illustrates the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to do it yourself, Blender (2.8+) comes with an addon built in for producing extra mesh objects including pipe joints.
Search 'extra' in the Addons section under Preferences and check 'Add Mesh: Extra objects'
[image]

You'll then see an extra section on the 'Add menu' with a Pipe Joints section:
[image]

Add an Pipe Elbow and change the settings to what you need:[image]
Then add a Solidify modifer, adjust its thicknes and apply it to give you the final object:
[image]

Comment: Not exactly what i want. I Want a rounded ElbowPipe.

Comment: Ok. Probably best to use the spin tool in that case. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VC89Qfw9pkg from about 6.30 onwards.

Comment: Aaah. that did the trick :D

Comment: Good! Usefull tool!